# How to create a pull request with 2 source branches and 1 destination branch in two parallel project modules?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

So lastly I have been working on a Java web app, built using servlets. This app consists of a project and many subprojects. I have been having some problems when creating branches. Let me explain a little bit simpler. For example I have a task to solve. Firstly I have to see the code and understand in what subproject the changes should be done, but there are some tasks that may rely on changes in more than one subproject. When I create a branch in bitbucket I also specify the subproject, but when the task relies on more than one subproject I have to create another branch for the other subproject. The problem stays in the part that although I have one feature to do, I end up with more than one branch to merge. So when i create a pull request in bitbucket, I can only specify one source branch and one destination branch, but what i need is to specify all the branches that are related with this feature. Is there something i can do?